What does num_entities in Milvus collection increase when one overwrites existing entities
I had thought that num_entities would indicate the number of records (or whatever the correct term is) within a Milvus collection. However, I created 1 file - test_milvus.py to create a simple collection like so:
import numpy as np
from pymilvus import connections, Collection, CollectionSchema, FieldSchema, DataType

connections.connect(alias='default',host='localhost', port='19530')

# Define the schema
schema = CollectionSchema([FieldSchema("id", DataType.INT64, is_primary=True, max_length=100),
                           FieldSchema("vector", DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=2)])

# Create a collection
collection = Collection("test_collection", schema)

# Insert data
data = [{"id":i, "vector": np.array([i, i],dtype=np.float32)} for i in range(10)]
collection.insert(data)

# Flush data
collection.flush()

# Disconnect from the server
connections.disconnect(alias='default')

and another to get information on collections within a Milvus database = milvus_info.py - like so:
from pymilvus import Collection, connections, db, utility

def get_info (host: str = "localhost", port: str = "19530"):

    # Connect to Milvus (replace with your connection details)
    connections.connect(alias="default", host=host, port=port)  # Replace with your connection parameters

    # Print the list of databases and collections
    db_list = db.list_database()
    for db_name in db_list:
        print(f"Database: {db_name}")
        collection_list = utility.list_collections(using=db_name)
        if len(collection_list) == 0:
            print("  No collections")
        for collection_name in collection_list:
            print(f"  Collection: {collection_name}")
            temp_collection = Collection(name=collection_name)
            for info in temp_collection.describe():
                print(f"    {info}: {temp_collection.describe()[info]}")
            temp_collection.flush() #Note: Adding this line does not fix problem.
            print(f"   Number of entities: {temp_collection.num_entities}")
          
    # Disconnect from Milvus
    connections.disconnect(alias='default')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_info()

The first time I ran test_milvus followed by milvus_info.py, I got this output:
  $ python test_milvus.py 
  $ python milvus_info.py 
    Database: default
      Collection: test_collection
        collection_name: test_collection
        auto_id: False
        num_shards: 1
        description: 
        fields: [{'field_id': 100, 'name': 'id', 'description': '', 'type': <DataType.INT64: 5>, 'params': {}, 'is_primary': True}, {'field_id': 101, 'name': 'vector', 'description': '', 'type': <DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR: 101>, 'params': {'dim': 2}}]
        aliases: []
        collection_id: 450687678279804785
        consistency_level: 2
        properties: {}
        num_partitions: 1
        enable_dynamic_field: False
       Number of entities: 10

which struck me as odd, because there were only 2 vectors in the db.
However, if I run `test_milvus.py' again, the number of entities goes up to 20, even though no new vectors have been added:
$ python test_milvus.py 
$ python milvus_info.py 
Database: default
  Collection: test_collection
    collection_name: test_collection
    auto_id: False
    num_shards: 1
    description: 
    fields: [{'field_id': 100, 'name': 'id', 'description': '', 'type': <DataType.INT64: 5>, 'params': {}, 'is_primary': True}, {'field_id': 101, 'name': 'vector', 'description': '', 'type': <DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR: 101>, 'params': {'dim': 2}}]
    aliases: []
    collection_id: 450687678279804785
    consistency_level: 2
    properties: {}
    num_partitions: 1
    enable_dynamic_field: False
   Number of entities: 20

This happens even though I've only tried to add records that were already there. I would've expected num_entities to be 10, no matter how many time I run these files. The documentation says it returns the number of rows, but I can drive it arbitrarily high while still having only 10 rows. Is num_entities supposed to track all rows that ever existed???
Note: This also happens when I replace insert with upsert

In python, a fast way to get the number of entities is:
print(collection.num_entities)
But this method is not accurate because it only calculates the number from persisted segments, by quickly picking the number from etcd.
Every time a segment is persisted, the basic information of the segment is recorded in Etcd, including its row number. collection.num_entities sums up row numbers of all the persisted segments.
But this number doesn't count the deleted items. Let's say a segment has 1000 rows, and you call collection.delete() to delete 50 rows from the segment, the collection.num_entities always shows 1000 rows for you.
And collection.num_entities doesn't know which entity is overwritten. Milvus storage is column-based, all the new data is appended to a new segment. If you use upsert() to overwrite an existing entity, it also appends the new entity to a new segment, and creates a delete action at the same time, the delete action is executed asynchronously. A delete action doesn't change the original number of this segment recorded in etcd because we don't intend to update etcd frequently(large amount of update action to etcd will show down the entire system performance). So, the collection.num_entities doesn't know which entity is deleted since the original number in etcd is not updated.
Furthermore, collection.num_entities doesn't count non-persisted segments.
collection.query(output_fields=["count(*)"]) is a query request, executed by query nodes. It counts deleted items, and all segments including non-persisted. And collection.query() is slower than collection.num_entities.
If you have no delete/upsert actions to delete or overwrite the existing entities in a collection, then it is a fast way to check the row number of this collection by collection.num_entities. Otherwise, you should use collection.query(output_fields=["count(*)"]) to get the accurate row number.
